# How to compute link budget in a system with aero/space-borne integration

Tags: power, satellite, research, 5g

I am studying a system in 5G which are represented as a [combination terrestrial and non-terrestrial network](https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_NTN.html) (including satellite segments or HAP/LAP) [5G NTN]

it is a unified terrestrial aerospace network = a space segment- ground station - user equipment.

I understand it that if I want to compute link budget, I cannot compute link budget separately, it is unified, it should be studied jointly.

There is a lot publication about 5G NTN system, but I didn’t find an explanation how I can compute link budget for this system.

Could someone please explain how I can compute link budget such system?

***PS*** unified - seamless integration of satellite and terrestrial components. it makes to enable 5G user terminals on or close to the earth’s surface to connect to non-terrestrial base stations located on satellites.

As I understood, in such system we cannot differently study links, satellite - ground station, ground station- user terminals, satellite- user terminals. The link should be studied as link satellite-ground station-user terminals. it will be one complete link

**EDIT 1: Andy aka comment**

From: ["Non-Terrestrial Network Realities Call for New 5G Testing Approaches"](https://www.spirent.com/blogs/non-terrestrial-network-realities-call-for-new-5g-testing-approaches)

[image]

About frequencies:

[For FR1, 3GPP reached an agreement for the following NTN bands:](https://www.5gamericas.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/5G-Non-Terrestrial-Networks-2022-WP-Id.pdf)

1. • 1980-2010MHz / 2170-2200MHz is the “S-band”; In the International
   Telecommunications Union (ITU), this band is identified for both
   satellite and terrestrial component of the International Mobile
   Telecommunications (IMT) frameworks
2. • Part of the L-band is allocated to Maximum Segment Size (MSS),
   depending on GEO/non GEO composition

EDIT 2 Marcus Müller comment

[5G standards](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-terrestrial-5g-networks-solving-link-budget-terminal-derek-long) make Terrestrial Networks and satellite/HAP/LAP segments part of the ecosystem of the 5G connectivity infrastructure.

As I understood, it is like hybrid system, which uses a ground system and space system together to create a link.

Comment: Please embed a picture of the set-up you are considering and mark on the picture the carrier frequencies used along with data rates.

Comment: please really add more information. Maybe the references Noel Miller cites  [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/640865/how-to-compute-link-budget-in-a-system-with-aero-space-borne-integration) are relevant to this question as well?